# Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "Latin1_General_BIN" and "Latin1_General_CI_AS" in the equal to operation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
I am getting the following error
```

> Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "Latin1_General_BIN" and
>   "Latin1_General_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.

Code

```
SELECT @PARTS = SUM(Llines_1.[qty]) from pick 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN op AS Llines_1 ON pick.picknote = 
Llines_1.[order_no] WHERE (pick.batchid = @batchid) AND (product = @product)
group by product Order By product
```

I have tired using COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS  before the from but still get the same error.

```
SELECT @PARTS = SUM(Llines_1.[qty])  COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
from pick RIGHT OUTER JOIN op AS Llines_1 ON pick.picknote = Llines_1.
[order_no] WHERE (pick.batchid = @batchid) 
AND (product = @product) group by product Order By product
```

Comment: Please paste code with `COLLATE`. Which columns have differend collations?

Comment: Edited original to include code with COLLATE. I am not sure which columns have different collations, how would I determine this ?

Comment: Emma, you can view collation in a property page of column in SSMS

Comment: Do the collate on the join.... as well...

Comment: I get incorrect syntax near collate...SELECT @PARTS = SUM(Llines_1.[qty])  COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
from pick RIGHT OUTER JOIN COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS op AS Llines_1 ON pick.picknote = Llines_1. [order_no] WHERE (pick.batchid = @batchid) 
AND (product = @product) group by product Order By product

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I assume that collations of `picknote` and `order_no` are different
Try this:

```
SELECT @PARTS = SUM(Llines_1.[qty])  
from pick 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN op AS Llines_1 ON pick.picknote = Llines_1.[order_no] COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
WHERE (pick.batchid = @batchid) 
    AND (product = @product) group by product Order By product
```

Comment: I get this error now..Expression type float is invalid for COLLATE clause.

Comment: picknote is nvarchar(50) and order_no is char(10)

Comment: One minute, still had first COLLATE in there, will remove now.

Comment: Works ! Thank You very much for your help

Comment: Just now the Query is so slow and times out !!

Comment: Indexes on column "Latin1_General_BIN" will not work with `COLLATE`

Comment: You can use `ALTER TABLE` to make collation of those columns equal. Also note that your join will work like `INNER JOIN` because of `(pick.batchid = @batchid) ` condition

Comment: Within the query ? I cant make changes to fields data type directly due to other constraints

Comment: I afraid it's impossible to make indexes work on this column, you should seek another ways to optimize your query (Add computed column with right collation and index on it for example)

Comment: changed the COLLATE to the other column as COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN - super fast now ! thanks for your help.

Comment: @MikhailLobanov, Works perfectly in my case. I had 2 different databases to query simular PK. I was getting the same error. But after applying : `COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` at the end of Inner Join statement, All went well. many thanks